# Multiple Instances of Ninject Singleton Being Created

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm using Ninject for constructor injection in what should be a singleton scope, but my logs are very clearly showing that multiple threads with their own instances of the injected object at a time.

**Ninject Binding**

```
List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly> {
    typeof(DbContext).Assembly, // DataAccess
    typeof(ILogger).Assembly, // Infrastructure
    typeof(NullHelpers).Assembly, // Library
    typeof(Repository<>).Assembly, // Repository
    typeof(Logger).Assembly, // Service
    typeof(NinjectRegistrator).Assembly, // This project
    GuiAssembly, // The GUI project
};

kernel.Bind(x => x
    .From(assemblies)
    .Select(type => type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract)
    .BindDefaultInterface()
    .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope())
);
```

As you can see, I rely heavily on Ninject and its default binding: `ISearchRepository` automatically maps to `SearchRepository`, etc.

**The Injected Class**

```
public class SearchRepository : ISearchRepository
{
    private readonly ISettingRepository _settingRepository;
    public SearchRepository(ISettingRepository settingRepo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new class created");
        _settingRepository = settingRepo;
    }
}
```

What I am seeing in my logging is "new class created" being output multiple times very close together. This is a commercial-level application and there are multiple threads using this repository at a time. Most of the time it runs fine, but there will be waves when this object is apparently disposed and constructed multiple times in 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Is there any chance you've got multiple threads making requests? I have no idea how to clearly express this but Ninject may not be able to be singleton across multiple threads.

Comment: Yes that's absolutely the case. At any time we have several threads making requests at a time. This repository is being used in many parts of the code, all running on separate threads simultaneously.

Comment: Where is your kernel reference comming from? If you create multiple kernels, they can have their own instance of SearchRepository.

Comment: Oh that's an interesting point. For the main web project it's coming from `NinjectWebCommon.cs`, in a method marked with `PreApplicationStartMethod`, but there are several other background applications that use this repository in their own context and are passing in their own kernel references. What are the possible side-effects of making the kernel object static so all applications use the same reference?

Comment: Ninject Singleton is thread safe. But as @PalleDue said it's singleton per kernel instance. Side effect of sharing kernels may be lock contention (aside from shared bindings and duplicate bindings etc.). (Also you need to think about who's properly managing the lifetime of the kernel.)